# why does my unedited script started to fail suddenly?

Tags: python, mysql

So I have a python script that used to work flawlessly, and now started to fail. 
the script takes mbox file and transfer content to mysql.

here is the segment that fails, and It is tied to mysql syntax for some reason 
Error:

```
File "mb_sql.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "mb_sql.py", line 82, in main
    db.query(database_string)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'call (\n  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  subject VARCHAR(200) ,\n  sender VARCH' at line 1")
```

this is the part that fails based on the error above.

```
def main():   #line29 
#some sanity test
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    usage()
    exit(-2)   
  mbox = sys.argv[1]   
  db_name = sys.argv[2]
  if mbox[-5:] == '.mbox': db_table=mbox[:-5].lower().replace('/','').replace('-','')
  else:
    print "Please give an mbox file.\nQuitting..."
    exit(-2)
#mysql table creation string
#if you change the string, you'll have to change the related entries on the several mysql queries that take place bellow
#text2 is true when is_multipart() is True
  database_string = """
  CREATE TABLE %s (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject VARCHAR(200) ,
  sender VARCHAR(100) ,
  reply_to VARCHAR(100) ,
  cc VARCHAR(100) ,
  date VARCHAR(100),
  text LONGTEXT,
  text2 LONGTEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
  );
  """ % db_table


  try:
    db = _mysql.connect("localhost","root","")
  except _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: 
    print "Check that you gave the correct credentials to access the db. Quitting...\n"
    exit(-2)

  table_exists = 0
  existing_max_id = 0

#try to create database and/or table, if one or both exist try to use them
  try:
    db.query("create database %s" % db_name)
    db.query("use %s" % db_name)
    db.query(database_string)
  except _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: 
    print "Can't create database, seems that database %s exists. We'll use it then " % db_name
    db.query("use %s" % db_name)
    try:
        db.query(database_string)    #Line 82
    except _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError:  
        print "Can't create table, seems that table %s exists. We'll use it then " % db_table
        table_exists = 1
        db.query("select max(id) from %s" % db_table)
        r=db.store_result()
        existing_max_id = r.fetch_row()[0][0]
  except _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError:
      print "Access denied: User can't create the database. Quitting...\n" 
      exit(-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`call` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks to escape the name or use another name.

```
create table `call` ...
```

Comment: I knew that, but it was bothering me since I do not use any "call" keyword within the script

Comment: Look at the error message. It tries to create a table called `call`

Comment: oh I see, the mbox file itself named "call.mbox" ... that is silly lol...